# Sum total number inside two foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach, sum

I have two loops one which calls agents and another with calls a set of dates. The dates loop sits inside the agents loop. The intention is to count the amount of rows inside for each individual agent. What I get is an overall total being added up instead of an individual total for each agent that I require.

```
$company = $_SESSION['user']['company']; $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, company FROM users WHERE company = '".$company."' AND level = 'user' AND status = 'Active'");
    $sth->execute();
    $agents = $sth->fetchAll(); 

    foreach($agents as $name){

    $begin = new DateTime($date1);
    $end = new DateTime($date2);

    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);                         

    foreach($daterange as $date){

        $salesdates = $date->format("Y-m-d");

        $query = "SELECT unid FROM ".$company."_automated_responses WHERE title = 'Sale' AND date LIKE '".$salesdates."%' AND agent_id = '".$name['id']."'";
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();

        $salescount = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($salescount < 10){ $bonus = 0; }
        else if($salescount < 12){ $bonus = 25; }
        else if($salescount < 14){ $bonus = 40; }
        else if($salescount < 16){ $bonus = 50; }
        else if($salescount < 18){ $bonus = 70; }
        else if($salescount < 20){ $bonus = 85; }
        else if($salescount > 19){ $bonus = 100; }                              

        $total_bonus += $bonus;
        $total_salescount += $salescount;


    }

    echo $total_salescount.' - '.$name['firstname'].' '.$name['lastname'].' - '.$total_bonus.'<br />';

}
```

This is the output:

> 125 - Agent 1 - 115
>
> 245 - Agent 2 - 180
>
> 387 - Agent 3 - 400
>
> 517 - Agent 4 - 540

What it should look like is this:

> 125 - Agent 1 - 115
>
> 120 - Agent 2 - 75
>
> 142 - Agent 3 - 220
>
> 130 - Agent 4 - 140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set $total_salescount = 0; in the first loop. This way when it goes into the second loop it will start with a count of 0 rather than keep adding on to what is already there.

Comment: Perfect, such a simple solution great :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you forgot to reset `$total_bonus` and `$total_salescount` to zero in the beginning of  `foreach($agents as $name)` loop. Without the reset, those values keep growing across different values of `$name`.